# How to create range in swift for switch case.?

Tags: ios, swift, range, nsrange

How to create range in swift for  `0,5,10` &  `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9:`

```
 switch currentIndex {
        case 0,5,10:
            segment = .fullWidth
        case 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9:// Can't write infinity range here need formula
            segment = .fiftyFifty
        default:
            segment = .fiftyFifty
        }
```

example `let underFive:Range = 0.0..<5.0` so I can put `underFive` in switch case.

Comment: @Rob I just want to make formula using `Range` `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9:`. infinity means the range sequence can be long. not limited.

Comment: @Rob first will be 0,5,10,15,20.... and so on. vice versa in other case. how can I create `Range` object for that?

Comment: @Rob `x % 5` is great suggestion. But I am curious  can we make formula for `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 .. so on:` so I can handle multiple switch cases also

Answer (score 1):

If you want a test for multiples of fives

```swift
switch currentIndex {
case let x where x.isMultiple(of: 5): // multiples of five here
default:                              // if you reach here, every value not divisible by five
}
```

The `default` case handles your “infinite range” scenario because the values of 5, 10, 15, etc., were handled by the prior `case`.

In answer to your question, a range is defined by a lower bound, an upper bound, or both. A “partial range” is one that has a lower bound or an upper bound, but not both. E.g. `100...` is all integers 100 or larger. Or, combining with the “not multiple of five” logic:

```swift
switch currentIndex {
case let x where x.isMultiple(of: 5): // multiples of five here
case 100...:                          // non multiples of five that are 100 or more
default:                              // everything else
}
```

But a range is inherently defined by its upper and lower bounds. If there numbers you wish to exclude, you have to put that logic in an earlier `case` or add a `where` clause (or both). Or use `Set` rather than ranges.

---

You asked a separate question about constants/variables. You can use that fine:

```swift
let underFive = 0..<5

switch currentIndex {
case underFive:                       // under five
default:                              // five through 99
}
```

You only need to make sure that the underlying type of your range matches the type of the `currentIndex`.

Comment: or `case let x where x.isMultiple(of: 5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```swift
var currentIndex = 4
enum Segment {
    case nothing
    case fullWidth
    case fiftyFifty
}

var segment: Segment = .nothing

switch currentIndex {
case 0,5,10:
      segment = .fullWidth
case 1...4, 6...9 :
      segment = .fiftyFifty
default:
      segment = .fiftyFifty
}

print(segment)
```

this code work in playground

[image]